# coloring EU countries based on group number in R

Tags: r

I think it's easy but I can't figure it out.
So I have shp file with UE countries loaded to Rstudio.
I have also excel file exported to csv and loaded.

The data I have exported to csv just with 2 columns.

Country name in 1st column and group number in second one.

I would need code that based on this data and my shp file would colour each country on map according to group. ex. green for group 1, red for group 2 etc.

```
library(spdep)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)
setwd("C:/Users/PLDurkaPa/Desktop/r")
shape.mapki<-st_read("ue.shp")
shape.pojedyncza<-shape.mapki$geometry
dane.mapka<-read.csv("2013r.csv" ,header=T, sep=";" ,dec=",")

plot(shape.pojedyncza, col="white", bg="white", lwd=1)


brks1<-c(1,2,3,4)
cols<-c("azure","green","red","blueviolet")
plot(shape.pojedyncza,col=cols[findInterval(dane.mapka$grupa,brks1)],forcefill=FALSE)
```

so i came up with such code and it work pretty fine despite 1 important problem.

I want it to colour countries according to numbers that each country have assigned in dane.mapka in "grupa" column

however coloring that i'm receiving don't match the numbers from file.

ex. Denmark should be blueviolet but i'm getting red one

Comment: It's probably easy, take a look at workig with `leaflet` and/or `sf`-packages. I cannot provide a more detailed answer without sample data..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a minimal reproducible example. See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>